# Let user load some content on a web page on Dropbox with the click of a `Save to Dropbox` button

Tags: javascript, html, share, dropbox

I'd like to enhance some web pages of my site by giving the user the ability to automatically load some content (for example an image) on his/her Dropbox by just the click of a `Save to Dropbox` button.

Just with the simple logic available from Facebook, gPlus, Pinterest.

Is it possibile?

I explored the documentation but couldn't find and indication.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To let the user save in his/her Dropbox some files hostes on your web site you need the [Saver](https://www.dropbox.com/developers/saver)

As the documentation states it is required to create a Dropbox app and obtain a `data-app-key`.

The web page has to load the Dropbox *dropins* JavaScript API.

Finally adding a "Save to Dropbox" button `Saver button` just requires inserting a link:

`<a href="https://www.example.com/the-file-to-upload/a-default-filename" class="dropbox-saver"></a>`

The `Saver` can also be triggered via JavaScript API allowing, for example, to design a custom button.

Detailed reference is here https://www.dropbox.com/developers/saver